# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal, script, ubuntu-18.04

Can someone help me ??? i don't know where is the problem ??

> ./menu.sh: line 268: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
> ./menu.sh: line 271: syntax error: unexpected end of file

```
 submenuFTP () {
      local PS3='Please enter option: '
      local options=( "Install vsftp" "create ftp user" "Return to menu")
      local opt
      select opt in "${options[@]}"
      do
          case $opt in
              "Install vsftp")
                 ./vsftp/vsftp_install.sh
                  ;;
              "Create ftp user")
                  ./vsftp/create_ftp.sh
                  ;;           
              "Return to menu")
                  return
              ;;
          *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
      esac
  done
}

submenuDatabase () {
 local PS3='Please enter option: '
  local options=("MySQL" "MariaDB" "MongoDB" "Postgres" "Return to menu")
  local opt
  select opt in "${options[@]}"
  do
      case $opt in
          "Install MySQL ")
             ./Database/mysql.sh
              ;;
          "Install MariaDB")
              ./Database/mariadb.sh
              ;;
           "Install MongoDB")
              ./Database/mongodb.sh
              ;;
        "Install Postgres")
              ./Database/postgres.sh
              ;;
          "Return to menu")
              return
              ;;
          *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
      esac
  done
}

submenuEmail () {
 local PS3='Please enter option: '
  local options=("Install postfix" "Install anti-spam" "Install anti-virus" "Add domaine" "Add user mail" "Return to menu")
  local opt
  select opt in "${options[@]}"
  do
      case $opt in
          "Install postfix")
             ./mail/postfix_install.sh
              ;;
          "Install anti-spam")
              ./mail/spamassassin_install.sh
              ;;
           "Install anti-virus")
              ./mail/clamAV_install.sh
              ;;
        "Add domaine")
              ./mail/add_domain.sh
              ;;
         "Add user mail")
              ./mail/add_user.sh
              ;;
          "Return to menu")
              return
              ;;
          *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
      esac
  done
}
submenuawstats () {
 local PS3='Please enter option: '
  local options=("Install awstats"  "Add domain awstats" "Return to menu")
  local opt
  select opt in "${options[@]}"
  do
      case $opt in
          "Install awstats")
            ./Monitoring/awstats_install.sh
              ;;
           "Add domain awstats")
              ./Monitoring/awstats_add_domaine.sh
              ;;
          "Return to menu")
              return
              ;;
          *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
      esac
  done
}
 submenuprestashop () {
 local PS3='Please enter option: '
  local options=("Install prestashop"  "Add domain prestashop" Return to menu")
  local opt
  select opt in "${options[@]}"
  do
      case $opt in
          "Install prestashop")
            ./Monitoring/prestashop_install.sh
              ;;
           "Add domain prestashop")
              ./Monitoring/prestashop_add_domaine.sh
              ;;
          "Return to menu")
              return
              ;;
          *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
      esac
  done
}

submenuMonitoring () {
 local PS3='Please enter option: '
  local options=(  "Use awstats"  "Use prestashop" "Return to menu")
  local opt
  select opt in "${options[@]}"
  do
      case $opt in
          "Use awstats")
             submenuawstats
              ;;
           "Use prestashop")
              submenuprestashop
              ;;
          "Return to menu")
              return
              ;;
          *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
      esac
  done
}
submenuSecurity () {
local PS3='Please enter option: '
  local options=("Install certbot" "Secure web page" "Secure mail" "Return to menu")
  local opt
  select opt in "${options[@]}"
  do
      case $opt in
          "Install certbot")
              ./certbot/certbot_install.sh
              ;;
           "Secure web page")
              ./certbot/certbot_web.sh
              ;;
            "Secure mail")
               ./certbot/certbot_mail.sh
              ;;       
            "Secure FTP")
               ./certbot/certbot_FTP.sh
              ;;       
               "Return to menu")
              return
              ;;
          *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
      esac
  done
}

submenuwebserver () {
  local PS3='Please enter option: '
  local options=("Install Nginx" "Create web page" "Return to menu")
  local opt
  select opt in "${options[@]}"
  do
      case $opt in
            "Install Nginx ")
              ./serverWeb/nginx_install.sh
              ;;      
             "Create web page")
              ./serverWeb/nginx_add_page.sh
              ;;                  
          "Return to menu")
              return
              ;;
          *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
      esac
  done
}
submenuDNS () {
  local PS3='Please enter option: '
  local options=("Install PowerDNS" "Add domaine" "Return to menu")
  local opt
  select opt in "${options[@]}"
  do
      case $opt in
             "Install PowerDNS")
             ./DNS/power_install.sh
              ;;           
             "Add domaine")
              echo "you chose sub item 1"
              ;;                  
          "Return to menu")
              return
              ;;
          *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
      esac
  done
}
submenuCron () {
  local PS3='Please enter option: '
  local options=("Install Cron" "Add domaine" "Return to menu")
  local opt
  select opt in "${options[@]}"
  do
      case $opt in
             "Install Cron")
              ./cron/install_cron.sh
              ;;           
             "Add cron job for database")
              ./cron/cron_database.sh
              ;;
         "Add cron job for nginx")
              ./cron/cron_nginx.sh
              ;;
             "Add cron job for awstats")
              ./cron/cron_awstats.sh
              ;;
             "Add cron job for certbot")
              ./cron/cron_certbot.sh
              ;;
          "Return to menu")
              return
              ;;
          *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
      esac
  done
}
# main menu
local PS3='Please enter option: '
options=("File manager" "Databases" "Email" "Monitoring" "Security" "Web server" "Web server" "Cron job" "DNS server" "Main menu quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "File manager")
             submenuFTP
            ;; 
        "Databases")
            submenuDatabase
            ;;
    "Email")
            submenuEmail
            ;;
    "Monitoring")
              submenuMonitoring
            ;;
    "Security")
            submenuSecurity
            ;;
    "Web server")
            submenuwebserver
            ;;
    "DNS server")
            submenuDNS
            ;;
    "Cron job")
            submenuCron
            ;;  
        "Main menu quit")
            exit
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
```

done
the line 268 and 171 are :

```
268         *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
269     esac
270 done
271
```

Comment: local options=("Install prestashop"  "Add domain prestashop" Return to menu") is missing a quote

Comment: yes this is the problem thanx you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### ./menu.sh: line 268: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

```
local options=("Install prestashop" "Add domain prestashop" Return to menu")
```

is missing a quote `"` before `Return`.

Note you can use [ShellCheck – shell script analysis tool](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to check for errors in bash scripts.

Comment: Further proof that syntax highlighting really helps find these issues!